# carbon dioxide in liquid and gaseous phase with liquid water

Tags: solubility, phase

What are the differences between carbon dioxide solubility (miscibility, reaction) in liquid water when in gaseous ($\pu{<38 bar}$) and liquid ($>\pu{38 bar}$) phase? The temperature in my experiments is usually between $0$ and $\pu{5\!^\circ C}$. Is there more phase - interface for the reaction between water and $\ce{CO2}$ in the gaseous phase?

According to Henry's law for real gases (including a Poynting correction), the solubility should rise with the fugacity of the vapor. How is it however, when the carbon dioxide is liquid? When observing a pressure drop in a closed stirred vessel with liquid water and $\ce{CO2}$ on top of it, the pressure drop is much larger for gaseous $\ce{CO2}$ than for the liquid $\ce{CO2}$, this does not however imply a larger solubility? In my understanding it just means, that the liquid $\ce{CO2}$ is not that compressible and will mix in a different manner than gas and liquid water, resulting in a lower pressure drop.

Comment: The water doesn't care wether there is also some liquid CO2 in the same vessel. I'll doubt you find any significant change of CO2 solubility at 38 bars.

Comment: related, though I do not have access: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1015294905132

Answer (score 1):

At a given temperature a mixture of gaseous $\ce{CO2}$ and liquid $\ce{CO2}$ will have a particular pressure. Thus more liquid $\ce{CO2}$ doesn't mean that more $\ce{CO2}$ will dissolve in the water.

Obviously liquid $\ce{CO2}$ has a lot more matter per unit volume than gaseous $\ce{CO2}$. So a little liquid $\ce{CO2}$ makes a lot of $\ce{CO2}$ gas.